# How to convert a undirected graph to multigraph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

New to networkx library, I would like to know if there is a way to obtain a multi-graph from a unidrected graph generated using the `barabasi_albert_graph`.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: With what parameters for the barabasi graph?

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar number of nodes and edges mainly.